# Make subdomain die if not defined on ssl

Tags: ssl, nginx

I am currently running nginx and have an ssl certification that is only on my domain and no sub domains. I do however have some sub-domains I like to use on the non-ssl so I want to keep my wildcard subdomains.

I was wondering if there was a way to make all ssl subdomains die and not resolve to anything. I would make them redirect but because of my ssl certification, the scary error message pops up before the server redirect them. I would rather have the page come up as nothing.

THanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because of how SSL works, you will always have a "scary error message" if someone comes to https://sub.domain.com/ and your SSL certificate doesn't list `sub.domain.com` as one of its canonical names.

The only ways around this are:

1. old good "Dedicated IP+Dedicated certificate" for every subdomain you host in SSL
2. Wildcard certificate
3. Web server with [SNI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication) support in SSL and per subdomain certificates
4. A certificate with [SAN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subject_Alternative_Name) propogated with all your subdomains

Which one to choose depends on your budget and how many browser/OS combinations you have to support.

I hope it answers your question, feel free to clarify it if not.